# How to speed up simple linear algebra optimization probelm in Julia?

Tags: performance, julia

I implemented the LSDD changepoint detection method decribed in [1] in Julia, to see if I could make it faster than the existing python implementation [2], which is based on a grid search that looks for the optimal parameters.

I obtain the desired results but despite my best efforts, my grid search version of it takes about the same time to compute as the python one, which is still way too long for real applications.
I also tried using the Optimize package which only makes things worse (2 or 3 times slower).

Here is the grid search that I implemented :

```
using Random
using LinearAlgebra

"""
computes the square distance netween elements of
X and C. returns squared_dist.
squared_dist[ij] = ||X[:, i] - C[:, j]||^2
"""
function squared_distance(X::Array{Float64,1},C::Array{Float64,1})
    sqd = zeros(length(X),length(C))
    for i in 1:length(X)
        for j in 1:length(C)
            sqd[i,j] = X[i]^2 + C[j]^2 - 2*X[i]*C[j]
        end
    end
    return sqd
end

# """
# Multidimensional equivalent of squared_distance.
# """
# function squared_distance(X::Array{Float64,2},C::Array{Float64,2})
#     sqd = zeros(size(X)[2],size(C)[2])
#     for i in 1:size(X)[2]
#         for j in 1:size(C)[2]
#             sqd[i,j] = sum(X.^2)[i,:] + sum(C.^2)[i,:] -2*sum(X[i,:].*C[j,:])
#         end
#     end
#     return sqd
# end

function lsdd(x::Array{Float64,1},y::Array{Float64,1}; folds = 5, sigma_list = nothing , lambda_list = nothing)
    lx,ly = length(x), length(y)
    b = min(lx+ly,300)
    C = shuffle(vcat(x,y))[1:b]
    CC_dist2 = squared_distance(C,C)
    xC_dist2, yC_dist2 = squared_distance(x,C), squared_distance(y,C)
    Tx,Ty = length(x) - div(lx,folds), length(y) - div(ly,folds)
    #Define the training and testing data sets
    cv_split1, cv_split2 = floor.(collect(1:lx)*folds/lx), floor.(collect(1:ly)*folds/ly)
    cv_index1, cv_index2 = shuffle(cv_split1), shuffle(cv_split2)
    tr_idx1,tr_idx2 = [findall(x->x!=i,cv_index1) for i in 1:folds], [findall(x->x!=i,cv_index2) for i in 1:folds]
    te_idx1,te_idx2 = [findall(x->x==i,cv_index1) for i in 1:folds], [findall(x->x==i,cv_index2) for i in 1:folds]
    xTr_dist, yTr_dist = [xC_dist2[i,:] for i in tr_idx1], [yC_dist2[i,:] for i in tr_idx2]
    xTe_dist, yTe_dist = [xC_dist2[i,:] for i in te_idx1], [yC_dist2[i,:] for i in te_idx2]
    if sigma_list == nothing
        sigma_list = [0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.2, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 2.2, 3, 5]
    end
    if lambda_list == nothing
        lambda_list = [1.00000000e-03, 3.16227766e-03, 1.00000000e-02, 3.16227766e-02,
       1.00000000e-01, 3.16227766e-01, 1.00000000e+00, 3.16227766e+00,
       1.00000000e+01]
    end
    #memory prealocation
    score_cv = zeros(length(sigma_list),length(lambda_list))
    H = zeros(b,b)
    hx_tr, hy_tr = [zeros(b,1) for i in 1:folds], [zeros(b,1) for i in 1:folds]
    hx_te, hy_te = [zeros(1,b) for i in 1:folds], [zeros(1,b) for i in 1:folds]
    #h_tr,h_te = zeros(b,1), zeros(1,b)
    theta = zeros(b)

    for (sigma_idx,sigma) in enumerate(sigma_list)
        #the expression of H is different for higher dimension
        #H = sqrt((sigma^2)*pi)*exp.(-CC_dist2/(4*sigma^2))
        set_H(H,CC_dist2,sigma,b)
        #check if the sum is performed along the right dimension
        set_htr(hx_tr,xTr_dist,sigma,Tx), set_htr(hy_tr,yTr_dist,sigma,Ty)
        set_hte(hx_te,xTe_dist,sigma,lx-Tx), set_hte(hy_te,yTe_dist,sigma,ly-Ty)

        for i in 1:folds
            h_tr = hx_tr[i] - hy_tr[i]
            h_te = hx_te[i] - hy_te[i]
            #set_h(h_tr,hx_tr[i],hy_tr[i],b)
            #set_h(h_te,hx_te[i],hy_te[i],b)
            for (lambda_idx,lambda) in enumerate(lambda_list)
                set_theta(theta,H,lambda,h_tr,b)
                score_cv[sigma_idx,lambda_idx] += dot(theta,H*theta) - 2*dot(theta,h_te)
            end
        end
    end
    #retrieve the value of the optimal parameters
    sigma_chosen = sigma_list[findmin(score_cv)[2][2]]
    lambda_chosen = lambda_list[findmin(score_cv)[2][2]]
    #calculating the new "optimal" solution
    H = sqrt((sigma_chosen^2)*pi)*exp.(-CC_dist2/(4*sigma_chosen^2))
    H_lambda = H + lambda_chosen*Matrix{Float64}(I, b, b)
    h = (1/lx)*sum(exp.(-xC_dist2/(2*sigma_chosen^2)),dims = 1) - (1/ly)*sum(exp.(-yC_dist2/(2*sigma_chosen^2)),dims = 1)
    theta_final =  H_lambda\transpose(h)
    f = transpose(theta_final).*sum(exp.(-vcat(xC_dist2,yC_dist2)/(2*sigma_chosen^2)),dims = 1)
    L2 = 2*dot(theta_final,h) - dot(theta_final,H*theta_final)
    return L2
end

function set_H(H::Array{Float64,2},dist::Array{Float64,2},sigma::Float64,b::Int64)
    for i in 1:b
        for j in 1:b
            H[i,j] = sqrt((sigma^2)*pi)*exp(-dist[i,j]/(4*sigma^2))
        end
    end
end

function set_theta(theta::Array{Float64,1},H::Array{Float64,2},lambda::Float64,h::Array{Float64,2},b::Int64)
    Hl = (H + lambda*Matrix{Float64}(I, b, b))
    LAPACK.posv!('L', Hl, h)
    theta = h
end


function set_htr(h::Array{Array{Float64,2},1},dists::Array{Array{Float64,2},1},sigma::Float64,T::Int64)
        for (CVidx,dist) in enumerate(dists)
            for (idx,value) in enumerate((1/T)*sum(exp.(-dist/(2*sigma^2)),dims = 1))
                #h[CVidx][idx] = value
                h[CVidx][idx] = value
            end
        end
end

function set_hte(h::Array{Array{Float64,2},1},dists::Array{Array{Float64,2},1},sigma::Float64,T::Int64)
    for (CVidx,dist) in enumerate(dists)
        for (idx,value) in enumerate((1/T)*sum(exp.(-dist/(2*sigma^2)),dims = 1))
            h[CVidx][idx] = value
        end
    end
end


function set_h(h,h1,h2,b)
    for i in 1:b
        h[i] = h1[i] - h2[i]
    end
end



function getdiff(ts; window = 150)
    diff = []
    for i in 1:(length(ts)-2*window)
        pd1 = [ts[i+k] for k in 1:window]
        pd2 = [ts[i+window+k] for k in 1:window]
        push!(diff,lsdd(pd1,pd2)[1])
    end
    return diff
end

a,b = rand(500),1.5*rand(500)
@time print(lsdd(a,b))
```

The `set_H`, `set_h` and `set_theta` functions are there because I read somewhere that modifying prealocated memory in place with a function was faster, but it did not make a great difference.
To test it, I use two random distributions as input data :

```
x,y = rand(500),1.5*rand(500)
lsdd(x,y) #returns a value around 0.3
```

Now here is the version of the code where I try to use Optimizer :

```
function Theta(sigma::Float64,lambda::Float64,x::Array{Float64,1},y::Array{Float64,1},folds::Int8)
    lx,ly = length(x), length(y)
    b = min(lx+ly,300)
    C = shuffle(vcat(x,y))[1:b]
    CC_dist2 = squared_distance(C,C)
    xC_dist2, yC_dist2 = squared_distance(x,C), squared_distance(y,C)
    #the subsets are not be mutually exclusive !
    Tx,Ty = length(x) - div(lx,folds), length(y) - div(ly,folds)
    shuffled_x, shuffled_y = [shuffle(1:lx) for i in 1:folds], [shuffle(1:ly) for i in 1:folds]
    cv_index1, cv_index2 = floor.(collect(1:lx)*folds/lx)[shuffle(1:lx)], floor.(collect(1:ly)*folds/ly)[shuffle(1:ly)]
    tr_idx1,tr_idx2 = [i[1:Tx] for i in shuffled_x], [i[1:Ty] for i in shuffled_y]
    te_idx1,te_idx2 = [i[Tx:end] for i in shuffled_x], [i[Ty:end] for i in shuffled_y]
    xTr_dist, yTr_dist = [xC_dist2[i,:] for i in tr_idx1], [yC_dist2[i,:] for i in tr_idx2]
    xTe_dist, yTe_dist = [xC_dist2[i,:] for i in te_idx1], [yC_dist2[i,:] for i in te_idx2]
    score_cv = 0
    Id = Matrix{Float64}(I, b, b)
    H = sqrt((sigma^2)*pi)*exp.(-CC_dist2/(4*sigma^2))
    hx_tr, hy_tr = [transpose((1/Tx)*sum(exp.(-dist/(2*sigma^2)),dims = 1)) for dist in xTr_dist], [transpose((1/Ty)*sum(exp.(-dist/(2*sigma^2)),dims = 1)) for dist in yTr_dist]
    hx_te, hy_te  = [(lx-Tx)*sum(exp.(-dist/(2*sigma^2)),dims = 1) for dist in xTe_dist], [(ly-Ty)*sum(exp.(-dist/(2*sigma^2)),dims = 1) for dist in yTe_dist]
    for i in 1:folds
        h_tr, h_te = hx_tr[i] - hy_tr[i], hx_te[i] - hy_te[i]
        #theta = (H + lambda * Id)\h_tr
        theta = copy(h_tr)
        Hl = (H + lambda*Matrix{Float64}(I, b, b))
        LAPACK.posv!('L', Hl, theta)
        score_cv += dot(theta,H*theta) - 2*dot(theta,h_te)
    end
    return score_cv,(CC_dist2,xC_dist2,yC_dist2)
end

function cost(params::Array{Float64,1},x::Array{Float64,1},y::Array{Float64,1},folds::Int8)
    s,l = params[1],params[2]
    return Theta(s,l,x,y,folds)[1]
end

"""
Performs the optinization
"""

function lsdd3(x::Array{Float64,1},y::Array{Float64,1}; folds = 4)
    start = [1,0.1]
    b = min(length(x)+length(y),300)
    lx,ly = length(x),length(y)
    #result = optimize(params -> cost(params,x,y,folds),fill(0.0,2),fill(50.0,2),start, Fminbox(LBFGS(linesearch=LineSearches.BackTracking())); autodiff = :forward)
    result = optimize(params -> cost(params,x,y,folds),start, BFGS(),Optim.Options(f_calls_limit = 5, iterations = 5))
    #bboptimize(rosenbrock2d; SearchRange = [(-5.0, 5.0), (-2.0, 2.0)])
    #result = optimize(cost,[0,0],[Inf,Inf],start, Fminbox(AcceleratedGradientDescent()))
    sigma_chosen,lambda_chosen = Optim.minimizer(result)
    CC_dist2, xC_dist2, yC_dist2 = Theta(sigma_chosen,lambda_chosen,x,y,folds)[2]
    H = sqrt((sigma_chosen^2)*pi)*exp.(-CC_dist2/(4*sigma_chosen^2))
    h = (1/lx)*sum(exp.(-xC_dist2/(2*sigma_chosen^2)),dims = 1) - (1/ly)*sum(exp.(-yC_dist2/(2*sigma_chosen^2)),dims = 1)
    theta_final = (H + lambda_chosen*Matrix{Float64}(I, b, b))\transpose(h)
    f = transpose(theta_final).*sum(exp.(-vcat(xC_dist2,yC_dist2)/(2*sigma_chosen^2)),dims = 1)
    L2 = 2*dot(theta_final,h) - dot(theta_final,H*theta_final)
    return L2
end
```

No matter, which kind of option I use in the optimizer, I always end up with something too slow. Maybe the grid search is the best option, but I don't know how to make it faster... Does anyone have an idea how I could proceed further ?

**Remark** : I already posted this question on stackexchange, where I was pointed out that it might make more sense to post it here.

[1] : http://www.mcduplessis.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Journal-IEICE-2014-CLSDD-1.pdf
[2] : http://www.ms.k.u-tokyo.ac.jp/software.html

Comment: This code doesn't run. The types on the `set_h*` functions are all incorrectly typed. Can you fix this please?

Comment: @OscarSmith It runs on my computer ... Which version of julia do you have ? Or maybe this is due to the fact that I forgot to include the packages to import in my post. I corrected that.

Comment: I'm on Julia 1.1.1 and get `ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching set_H(::Array{Float64,2}, ::Array{Float64,2}, ::Float64, ::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  set_H(::Array{Float64,2}, ::Array{Float64,2}, ::Float64, !Matched::Int16)`
``

Comment: @OscarSmith Ok that's weird ... I wasn't excpecting to see Int64s, anyways I change the int16 to int64, does it work now ?

Comment: It still errors. Please make sure your code actually runs correctly

Comment: @OscarSmith What is your error ? It runs perfectly well on my computer (I just copied and pasted the provided code in a new file to be sure). ```a,b = rand(300), 2*rand(300)``` and ```lsdd(a,b)``` returns something around 0.5.

Comment: `ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching set_htr(::Array{Array{Float64,2},1}, ::Array{Array{Float64,2},1}, ::Float64, ::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  set_htr(!Matched::Array{Float64,1}, !Matched::Array{Float64,2}, ::Float64, ::Int64) at /home/oscardssmith/Documents/Code/2dIsing.jl:86`

Comment: Hmm .. I don't really know what was going on, but I modified a few type indications in the functions an updated my post. It passes the tests on travis so it should definitely work on your machine this time.